# How to embed :id parameter in the middle of a URL in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using react-router-dom for the routing on my react app. I want to have these url paths "/offers/:id/:title", where :id and :title change, whenever I do this, the params is set so that the rest of the string equals "id" and there isn't a title. For example if the url I searched is "/offers/work/work-is-fun", the "id" = 'offers/work-is-fun' and "title" is undefined. Is there a way to get around this? So that "id" = 'offers'?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
"/offers(/:id)(/:title)"
```

or

```js
"/offers/:id?/:title?"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach.

```js
import {
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";


const {id, title} = useParams<{ title: string; id: string }>();



<Route path="/teste/:id/:title" exact>
   <SomeOtherComponent  />
</Route>
```